# "Failed at the lzma-native@3.0.8 install script" When I deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

whenever I try to deploy my discord.js bot I get an error `Failed at the lzma-native@3.0.8 install script` , I specified node.js version and I tried to specify the npm version but I still get the same problem.I'm using Node.js `14.15.4` and npm `6.14.10` Here is the full log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.15.4...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.10
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > nodemon@2.0.7 postinstall /tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       
       > lzma-native@3.0.8 install /tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build
       
       node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-pre-gyp.addaleax.net/lzma-native/lzma_native-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64.tar.gz 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for lzma-native@3.0.8 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-pre-gyp.addaleax.net/lzma-native/lzma_native-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64.tar.gz 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for lzma-native@3.0.8 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
       gyp: Call to 'sh liblzma-config.sh "/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/build" "/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/deps/xz-5.2.3.tar.bz2"' returned exit status 77 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
       gyp ERR! configure error 
       gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
       gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1083-aws
       gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64/lzma_native.node" "--module_name=lzma_native" "--module_path=/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64"
       gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native
       gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
       gyp ERR! not ok 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64/lzma_native.node --module_name=lzma_native --module_path=/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64' (1)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
       node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1083-aws
       node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
       node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native
       node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
       node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
       node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
       Failed to execute '/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_96ae59ea_/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64/lzma_native.node --module_name=lzma_native --module_path=/tmp/build_96ae59ea_/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-linux-x64' (1)
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! lzma-native@3.0.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the lzma-native@3.0.8 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Ci6p9/_logs/2021-01-30T16_41_27_068Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Have you checked that this version is available on npm package manager or not?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem was because a conflict with a dependency `ffmpeg-binaries`
So I basically uninstalled it.

```
npm uninstall ffmpeg-binaries
```